# jQuery UI Tab Loading a url

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I've been trying to make a jQuery tab UI like in the following [Better alternative to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102878/better-alternative-to-an-iframe) but after hours of troubleshooting I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          $("#tabs").tabs();
          });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="one.html"><span>One</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="two.html"><span>Two</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="three.html"><span>Three</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

So in my folder I have test.html (the above), one.html, two.html, and three.html. When I load test.html, any tab I select just says Loading... and the html pages never load.

For a more visual explanation, I'm trying to do what this demo is but with html pages:
http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/jquerytabs/test.cfm

Please help haha I'm so lost as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance :)