# How does the jQuery UI Tab Functionality work with a URL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to follow the example:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>    $(function() {        
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ beforeLoad: function( event, ui )
 { ui.jqXHR.error(function()
 {  ui.panel.html( "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +  "If this wouldn't be a demo." );               
 });           
 }        
});    
});    
</script>
    <div id="tabs">    
    <ul>        
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>        
        <li>
        <a href="http://mywebsite/sompage.asp?item=123">Tab 1</a>
        </li>       

         </ul>    
         <div id="tabs-1">       
            <p>Stuff preloaded.  Just text.p>    
         </div>
     </div>
```

When I click "Tab 1," I get nothing but the error message.  How does the tab get created to display any data at all?  I only see `<div id="tabs-1">`.  Preloaded works fine, url, no.  What am I doing wrong?  What is it expecting back from my .asp page?  Do I have to create a tab for it?

Thanks.  Sorry for the formatting, but when I copy and paste from the jquery page, it gets jumbled up.  I tried to clean it up.

[jQuery UI Tab Loading a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532301/jquery-ui-tab-loading-a-url)  Has no answer

Comment: replace `ui.panel.html( "Coul` with `console.log(arguments)` and respond with the error reason.

Comment: Is the URL pointing to the same web site as the page containing the tab? If not, cross-domain AJAX prevents loading it.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the error help.